# Why environment variable does not change?

Tags: c#, windows

I have Windows 7 and I am using this code:

```
        string genericLib = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["GenericLib"];
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(genericLib))
        {
            string path = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Path");

            if (path != null && !path.Contains(genericLib))
            {
                path = genericLib + ";" + path;
                Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("path", path);
            }

            string new_path = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Path");
        }
```

Debugger shows me that **new_path** variable does contain new path that I added. But next time when I execute this code added path is no longer there.

Does someone know why is that?

Comment: This is pretty much answered straight from the description summaries of the overloads of [`Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.setenvironmentvariable(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z46c489x(v=vs.110).aspx) of that method says (emphasis mine):

> Creates, modifies, or deletes an environment variable stored **in the current process**.

So you are changing the environment variable for the process only. Use [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96xafkes(v=vs.110).aspx) instead:

```
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("path", path, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);
```